# How to solve this Ice block puzzle?

Tags: ittle-dew-2

[image]

How do you solve this puzzle? They are ice blocks that slide all the way till they hit a wall or another ice block and they can only be pushed. They can't move on the sand(yellowish areas) and one of them has to end up on an orange switch because I can stand on the other switch to unlock the cheat. [image]

Comment: I think I see the solution, but I need some confirmation; the edge of the sand acts like a wall to the sliding blocks?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I'm understanding correctly (you only need the ice blocks to press one switch while you stand on the other, and the the edge of the sand acts like a wall to the sliding blocks) the solution is as follows:

[image]

1. Push the top block (**1**) *up* so it rests just above the switch.
2. Push the left block (**2**) *up* against the wall, and then to the *right* so it rests against the grey blocks.
3. Push the right block (**3**) *left* against the sand, then *up* so it rests against the wall.
4. Push block **3** *right* so it stops next to block **2**.
5. Push block **3** *up* so that it will rest on the top orange switch (block **1** prevents it from overshooting)
6. Step on the lower orange switch in the middle of the room.

Answer (score 0):

*SPOILERS*

Or wait until you get the ice thing, don't remember if it changes into a ring or always is one.